# Ansible playbook return result

Tags: ansible

Following is my Ansible Playbook:

```
name: Show the banner login
ios_command:
  commands: show running-config | beg banner login
register: test
```

If I want to display the result of the output for example;

- Failed when result of command show nothing
- Pass when result of command show value

What should I do ?

Comment: This is the piece of documentation your need: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your playbook

```
  - name: message
    assert:
      that: test.rc == 0
      fail_msg: "Failed"
      success_msg: "PASS"
```